# Convergence of a complex Fourier series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi (2k+1)i} e^{(2k+1)it} $$

(*) For $n=2k$ the terms are zero.

I'd be glad for a guidance. How do I approach this? Should I split it for Real/Imaginary?

Comment: Wait, Let me edit the question please

Comment: Okay, that last edit addresses what I was concerned about.

Comment: Now the question is: which kind of convergence? $L^2$-convergence, pointwise, uniform? Probably pointwise, I guess.

Comment: I tend to write fast (and sometimes omitting important things. Sorry)

Comment: Yes, pointwise.

Comment: (I also need to present the function the series converges to)

Comment: Have you learned Dirichlet's test for convergence?

Comment: I don't understand the "For $\;n=2k\;$ the terms are zero" condition: what $\;n\;$, anyway?

Comment: @Timbuc, I'm sorry for bad notation. Please notice the summation is for $n=2k+1$. Meaning, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{odd}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Yes, we've learned it. I'll just have to refresh my mind on it

Comment: An idea:

$$\frac{2\,e^{(2k+1)it}}{\pi(2k+1)i}=\int\frac2\pi\left(e^{(2k+1)it}\right)dt$$and now:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{(2k+1)it}=e^{it}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{2it}\right)^k$$
Now, here's a problem: the above is a cute geometric sum **but** its constant ratio fulfills $\;\left|e^{2it}\right|=1\;$ , and this is a problem for convergence.

Comment: Maybe we should use Cauchy/Cesaro summation to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think splitting into real and imaginary parts helps here. Rearranging and grouping each $e^{(2k+1)it},\, k\geqslant 0$ with $e^{-(2k+1)it}$ shows that

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)i}e^{(2k+1)it} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)i}\bigl(e^{(2k+1)it}-e^{-(2k+1)it}\bigr) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \bigl(2k+1)t\bigr)}{(2k+1)}$$

is real, however.

To show convergence, in the original form we need to distinguish $t\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \pi\mathbb{Z}$. For $t = m\pi$, we obtain

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^m}{\pi(2k+1)i}$$

which does not converge in the usual sense [independent convergence of the series for $k\geqslant 0$ and the series for $k < 0$], but the symmetric partial sums converge to $0$.

For $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \pi\mathbb{Z}$, the Dirichlet test shows convergence. In the rewritten real form, the distinction between $t\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $t\notin \pi\mathbb{Z}$ need not be made, Dirichlet's test works for all $t$ then.

To find the function whose Fourier series this is, you could split the series and replace the $e^{it}$ with $z$, giving

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)i} z^{2k+1} - \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi(2m+1)i}\overline{z}^{(2m+1)}.$$

The power series (one in $z$ and one in $\overline{z}$) have a radius of convergence $1$, we can explicitly determine their values for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, and it is reasonable to hope that taking the limit $\lvert z\rvert\to 1$ gives the real function whose Fourier series we are given.

There are several ways to prove that the "reasonable hope" is indeed not misleading (that the method works in principle), but one can also verify it by computing the Fourier coefficients of the thusly determined function.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! It helped me a lot!

Comment: Why can we rearrange the terms? Not all terms are positive. How do I explain it?

Comment: Hmm, "rearranging" might not have been the best choice of words, since what I've done is a very special thing, not a general rearrangement. A series $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k$ is said to be convergent if both series, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}$ converge. Now if we have two series $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty b_m$ and $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty c_m$, we can look at the series $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (b_m + c_m)$. If two of the series converge, then so does the third, and the limit of the last is the sum of the limits of the first two. That is what

Comment: I have done here, but without verifying that indeed the series converge, since it was just meant to show that the sum is real, not to show convergence. The re-grouping to the real series only can show the weaker "symmetric convergence" of the original series, that is, $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=-N}^N a_k$ exists, not the true pointwise convergence of both halves, but for Fourier series that is often all one needs. For $t\notin \pi\mathbb{Z}$, we have true convergence, so then the re-grouping is fully legitimate. For $t\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$, it is only weakly legitimate, as mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding to Dirichlet's test: In the rewritten form it does make sense, since $\sin((2n+1)t)$ is bounded and $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ is monotonically decreasing to $0$. **BUT**, in the original form the exponent isn't bounded.

Comment: The partial sums are bounded for $t\notin \pi\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $$\sum_{k=0}^N e^{(2k+1)it} = e^{it}\frac{1-e^{(2N+2)it}}{1-e^{2it}},$$ which is bounded by $\frac{1}{\lvert\sin t\rvert}$. So Dirichlet's test is applicable to each half of the original series.